# Use Dropbox calls right after login

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-java

So I am currently working on a simple Dropbox Gallery App as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044326/android-dropbox-check-for-differences).

When I click the button I have to choose the Dropbox Account I want to use.
When I've chosen one Dropbox loads briefly and I return back to the previous screen, where I originally pressed the "Dropbox-Button".

When I click the Button again I get my gallery as I desired.
Now I want to get rid of that extra click - So the user clicks the Dropbox button and after a short time (the login time?) the user can see the requested image gallery.

The following class is the one that is used for the Authentication and I don't know how I can implement some kind of "onSuccess" functionality for it:

```
public class Auth {

    public static void startOAuth2Authentication(Context context, String appKey) {

        if (!AuthActivity.checkAppBeforeAuth(context, appKey, true /*alertUser*/)) {
            return;
        }

        // Start Dropbox auth activity.
        String apiType = "1";
        String webHost = "www.dropbox.com";
        Intent intent =  AuthActivity.makeIntent(context, appKey, webHost, apiType);
        if (!(context instanceof Activity)) {
            // If starting the intent outside of an Activity, must include
            // this. See startActivity(). Otherwise, we prefer to stay in
            // the same task.
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static String getOAuth2Token() {
        Intent data = AuthActivity.result;

        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String token = data.getStringExtra(AuthActivity.EXTRA_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        String secret = data.getStringExtra(AuthActivity.EXTRA_ACCESS_SECRET);
        String uid = data.getStringExtra(AuthActivity.EXTRA_UID);

        if (token != null && !token.equals("") &&
                secret != null && !secret.equals("") &&
                uid != null && !uid.equals("")) {
            return secret;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the successful app authorization event in `onResume`, as shown in the [Dropbox API v2 Java SDK Android example app](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android) here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/7ecc15cf0f51d6ae2ba5cdb334aac2c2f3474b87/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/DropboxActivity.java#L16

That's where you should call `getOAuth2Token` to get the access token from the app authorization.

Comment: That is what I thought of first too, the problem is that I do not want to go into the gallery right after I enter the screen where the "Log into Dropbox"-Button is located. I want to go to the gallery when the Dropbox-Button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved my problem with a repetitive Runnable like this:

```
public class MyActiviry extends BaseActivity {

    // ...

    private Handler handler;
    private Context context;

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;
        handler = new Handler();

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    public void selectFromDropBox(DropboxImageProvider dropboxImageProvider) {
        final DropboxImageProvider provider;

        showLoadingOverlay();

        if (dropboxImageProvider == null) {
            provider = DropboxImageProvider.getInstance(/* ... */);
        } else {
            provider = dropboxImageProvider;
        }

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (provider.isLoggedIn()) {
                    provider.requestThumbnails((Activity) context);
                } else {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000L);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // ...

}
```

It might not be the most beautiful solution but it works for me.